# ASP.NET Core MVC Xreturn view multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am showing checkbox list in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. I am pulling data from a database. I don't have any problems displaying one item, but if I want to show more than one item, I get a problem. How can I solve it?

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var item = _context.Cihazlar.ToList();

    StudentCourseViewModel m1 = new StudentCourseViewModel();
    m1.AvailableCourses = item.Select(vm => new CheckBoxItem()
            {
                Id = vm.Id,
                Title = vm.Model,
               IsChecked = false
            }).ToList(); 
 
     return View(m1);
}
```

There is no problem in my code as above. The checkboxlist in `m1` appears on the page, but if I make my code as below, I get an error.

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var item = _context.Cihazlar.ToList();

    StudentCourseViewModel m1 = new StudentCourseViewModel();
    m1.AvailableCourses = item.Select(vm => new CheckBoxItem()
            {
                Id = vm.Id,
                Title = vm.Model,
               IsChecked = false
            }).ToList(); 
 
    var item2 = _context.HardwareSoftware.ToList();

    StudentCourseViewModel m2 = new StudentCourseViewModel();            
    m2.AvailableCourses2 = item2.Select(vm => new CheckBoxItem()
            {
                Id = vm.Hardware_Software_Id,
                Title = vm.Hardware_Software_Name,
                IsChecked = false
            }).ToList();
 
    return View(m1, m2);
}
```

How can I show `m1` and `m2` at the same time?

Comment: One view, one view model. So send a list of data to the view and change the view model in the view to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, you can make like the following.

Declare a compound data model:

```cs
public class UnitedViewModel 
{
    public StudentCourseViewModel CihazlarCourses { get; set; } // Cihazlar
    public StudentCourseViewModel HSCourses { get; set; } // HardwareSoftware
}
```

The `Create` action method:

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new UnitedViewModel();

    var item = _context.Cihazlar.ToList();

    model.CihazlarCourses = new StudentCourseViewModel();
    model.CihazlarCourses.AvailableCourses = item.Select(vm => new CheckBoxItem()
            {
                Id = vm.Id,
                Title = vm.Model,
               IsChecked = false
            }).ToList(); 

    var item2 = _context.HardwareSoftware.ToList();

    model.HSCourses = new StudentCourseViewModel();            
    model.HSCourses.AvailableCourses = item2.Select(vm => new CheckBoxItem()
            {
                Id = vm.Hardware_Software_Id,
                Title = vm.Hardware_Software_Name,
                IsChecked = false
            }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Then declare the data view model in the `Create.cshml` as below:

```
@model UnitedViewModel 
   
    .... Your code here will use the `@Model.CihazlarCourses` and the `@Model.HSCourses`
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I implemented what you wrote, but I'm having trouble with the create.cshtml page. When I change the model, I get an error in the data inside the StudentCourseViewModel model I used. When I define them in UnitedViewModel, the values ​​returned in the checkboxes appear as null and give an error message. How can I fix? I'm just learning, I searched, but I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: I solved my problem, I was getting the wrong value from the model in the create.cshtml page. Thanks for your help.